# Keep inner interface method names in proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard

Lets say I have..

```
public class SomeClass {


    public interface someInterface {

        public void firstMethod(String variable);


        public void secondMethod(String variable);


        public void thirdMethod();

    }
}
```

and I do..

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class com.somepackage.SomeClass {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep public interface com.somepackage.someInterface {*;}
```

I end up with

```
public interface someInterface {

        public void a(String variable);


        public void a(String variable);


        public void a();

    }
```

How do I ensure this interface's method names are not obfuscated while still obfuscating the rest of the class?

Comment: If its inside of a class, shouldn't the proguard parameters include your outer class as part of the full name of the interface?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ProGuard uses the naming convention of Java bytecode, as seen in class file names and stacktraces. Therefore:

```
-keep public interface com.somepackage.SomeClass$someInterface {*;}
```

Comment: I lost an hour because I used above syntax which didn't work for me. The reason was that I define my interfaces without the public accessor (it's obsolete since all interfaces are public). In that case you need to use: -keep interface com.somepackage.SomeClass$someInterface {*;}. I think ProGuard should be "clever" enough to handle his case automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and it seemed to work:

```
-keep interface com.somepackage.SomeClass$someInterface
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for how to keep a custom annotation (which is defined in a @interface in java) retaining its all members,

you should actually use like below to keep it:

```
-keep @interface com.your.annotation.interface. {*;}
```

Comment: isnt that you should have it like -keep @interface com.your.annotation.interface.** { *; }
or it is the different meaning?